# Setting NEI to Cheat Mode Doesn't Work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Setting NEI (Minecraft) to Cheat mode Doesn't work My Lock Mode is set to -1 and my Cheat mode is set to 2 but it still doesn't work I'm kinda confused because most of the forums i looked at told me to set these things to what they already were I also made sure i was in Global Settings not world which had the cheat mode locked (Playing Tekkit Legends if that has anything to do with it)

Comment: Is this singleplayer or multiplayer?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this off in the configuration file. Go to the config folder (probably C:/Users/YourName/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/config ) and find NEI.cfg . Open it with Notepad, and change the line that says lockmode=0 to lockmode=-1 . This will unlock the option to switch to cheat mode in the options menu in-game.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that cheat mode does not work in multiplayer if you are not a server OP.